# Find number of skew-symmetric matrices of order $3\times 3$ in which all non-diagonal elements are different

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find number of skew-symmetric matrices of order $3\times 3$ in which all non-diagonal elements are different and belong to the set $\{-9,-8,-7,...,7,8,9\}$

My Attempt:
I did a simple calculation and obtained $$\binom{9}{3}\times(3!)\times 2^3=4032$$

But answer given is $$\frac{4032}{6}=672$$

Why has it been divided by $6$

Comment: Hi, can you explain how you got your answer? I am not able to understand it.

Comment: @aarbee Since it is skew symmetric matrix so all the elements in diagonal will be zero. So first choose 9 elements either from set $\{-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1\}\;$ or $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ because $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}\; \forall i\neq j$ for skew symmetric matrix. So $9\choose 3$. but  three entries can be arranged in three place say $a_{12}, a_{13}, a_{23}$ in $3!$ ways and $2^3$ because we can permute $a_{12}\;$ and $a_{21}\;$, $a_{13}\;$ and $a_{31},\;$ $a_{23}$ and $a_32\;$ so number of ways are ${9\choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 2^3$.

Comment: @mathophile, 1) When you say 'choose 9 elements', I think you want to say 3 elements. 2) I didn't understand 2 to the power 3. Can you explain further please? 3) Can you convert your comment to answer so that I could award bounty to it? Thanks.

Comment: @mathophile Also, we have 2 sets of 9 elements. Need not we multiply by $^2C_1$?. Also, are we considering the possibility that in the upper triangle, we could have two positive and one negative number or two negative and one positive?

Comment: @mathophile what if we just do $^{18}P_{3}?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given answer would be correct if the problem specified "up to permutations of rows and columns". But it did not, and your answer is correct.

Comment: Hi. Any chance you could explain the answer? I am not able to understand the OP's approach.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @aarbee in comment section i am providing a detailed solution to given problem.

Definition: $\;(i)\;$Since it is skew symmetric matrix so all the elements in diagonal will be zero.

$\;(ii)\;$ $a_{ij}=−a_{ji}\;∀\;i≠j$ for skew symmetric matrix.

**Explanation of $9\choose 3$**

First choose $3$ elements either from set $\{−9,−8,−7,−6,−5,−4,−3,−2,−1\}$ or $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ because $a_{ij}=−a_{ji}\;∀\;i≠j$ for skew symmetric matrix. So number of ways to choose $3$ elements out of $9$ is ${9\choose 3}$
and these three entries can be arranged in three place say $a_{12},a_{13},a_{23}$ in $3!$ ways

**We can't do ${18 \choose 3}\cdot3!$ because in this way we can get $3$ elements $1,-1,\;2$ which won't form skew-symmetric matrix because in this case $3$ elements in upper diagonal or lower diagonal will $1 , -1, \; 2$.**

And $2^3$ because we can permute $a_{12}$ and $a_{21},\;$ $\;a_{13}$ and $a_{31},\;$ $\;a_{23}$ and $a_{32}$.

So  total number of ways are  ${9\choose 3}\cdot3!\cdot2^3$

**Detailed explanation of $2^3$:** Let say selected elements are $1,2,3$

Here are those $8$ matrcies whose elmenets are $1,2,3$

$\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1 & 2\\
 -1 & 0 & 3\\ -2 & -3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & -1 & 2\\
 1 & 0 & 3\\ -2 & -3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1 & -2\\
 -1 & 0 & 3\\ 2 & -3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1 & 2\\
 -1 & 0 & -3\\ -2 & 3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & -1 & -2\\
 1 & 0 & 3\\ 2 & -3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & -1 & 2\\
 1 & 0 & -3\\ -2 & 3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1 & -2\\
 -1 & 0 & -3\\ 2 & 3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$ $\begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & -1 & -2\\
 1 & 0 & -3\\ 2 & 3 & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix},\;$.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence: "First choose $3$ elements either from set ${−9,−8,−7,−6,−5,−4,−3,−2,−1}$ or ${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$". Are you saying that the $3$ elements should be all positive or all negative?

Comment: @Taladris I am choosing all the positive number and putting them in upper diagonal because this way we will have less case work. In the end we are multiplying by $8$ so it will have all the possibilities when upper diagonal elements are negative also.

Comment: You're right. I figured it out after sending the comment. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Even if we do $^{18}C_3$, we'll still get skew symmetric matrices but there, non-diagonal elements won't always be different.

Comment: @aarbee Hi, We may get skew-symmetric matrices but we have to do much case work. And if i clear your doubt you can give bounty to answer.